# Most probable position of finding an electron represented in cartesian and spherical coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, coordinate-systems, probability

Consider the probability of finding an electron within a region:

$$P= \iiint |\psi(x,y,z)|^2  dxdydz$$

I would think that The probability of finding an electron at a single point in space would be defined as:

$$P(x,y,z)= \lim_{dx,dy,dz\rightarrow 0} \int_{x}^{x+dx}\int_{y}^{y+dy}\int_{z}^{z+dz}|\psi(x,y,z)|^2  dxdydz$$

Assuming $|\psi(x,y,z)|^2 = \psi^2_{x}(x)\psi^2_{y}(y)\psi^2_{z}(z)$ we then obtain:

$$\lim_{dx\rightarrow 0} \int_{x}^{x+dx} \psi^2_{x}(x)dx \lim_{dy\rightarrow 0} \int_{y}^{y+dy} \psi^2_{y}(y)dy\lim_{dz\rightarrow 0} \int_{z}^{z+dz} \psi^2_{z}(z)dz$$

By the definition of the derivative and by the fundamental theorem of calculus it takes no effort to show

$$P(x,y,z) = [\psi^2_{x}(x)dx][\psi^2_{y}(y)dy][\psi^2_{z}(z)dz]$$

$$P(x,y,z) = |\psi(x,y,z)|^2 dxdydz$$
Which makes sense, the probability density times the volume element.
If this is the probability of finding a particle at a point in space, the point with the highest probability of finding an electron satisfies $max(|\psi(x,y,z)|^2dxdydz)$ since dxdydz are scalars and do not depend upon x,y,z , we have also have that this point satisfies $max(|\psi(x,y,z)|^2)$

Now my understanding lacks when considering the same thing in polar coordinates:
The probability of finding a particle within a region is:

$$\iiint |\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 r^2 \sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi$$

The probability of finding a particle at  point in space, following in the same spirit as before I would assume is:
$$P(x,y,z)= \lim_{dr,d\theta,d\phi\rightarrow 0} \int_{r}^{r+dr}\int_{\theta}^{\theta+d\theta}\int_{\phi}^{\phi+d\phi}|\psi(x,y,z)|^2 r^2 \sin(\theta)  dr d\theta d\phi$$

Assuming $|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 = \psi^2_{r}(r)\psi^2_{\theta}(\theta)\psi^2_{\phi}(\phi)$ we then obtain:

$$p(r,\theta,\phi)= \lim_{dr\rightarrow 0} \int_{r}^{r+dr} \psi^2_{r}(r)r^2dr\lim_{d\theta\rightarrow 0} \int_{\theta}^{\theta+d\theta} \psi^2_{\theta}(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta\lim_{d\phi\rightarrow 0} \int_{\phi}^{\phi+d\phi} \psi^2_{\phi}(\phi)d\phi$$

Likewise it is not hard to show that

$$P(r,\theta,\phi) = [\psi^2_{r}r^2dr][\psi^2_{\theta}(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta][\psi^2_{\phi}(\phi)d\phi]$$

$$P(r,\theta,\phi) =|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 r^2 \sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi$$

Hence in order to find the position that maximises the probability I would need to solve $$ max[|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 r^2 \sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi] = max[|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 r^2 \sin(\theta)]$$
where i have cancelled the differential elements since these are scalars that do not depend upon any variable

And when the dust settles we have two expressions for the position that maximises the probability.

$$max[|\psi(x,y,z)|^2] = max[|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2]$$

$$max[|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 r^2 \sin(\theta)]$$

Clearly the choice of coordinates should not impact the result, expressing the former expression in terms of spherical coordinates shows the maximum satisfies two different equations and thus I would think have different maximum position values.

Where is the logic in my thinking going wrong?

I guess the logic goes wrong when I simply cross off the differentials towards the end, since dv are the same in both cases, but i am treating one as constants and one as variable dependant.
[image]

Comment: The reason i crossed off the differentials is that i want to solve the equation for the maxima, and working with pure variables instead of differentials makes life seem easier. Which one should i use when calculating the maximum? i would intuatively say the first, it fits the cartesian model well when the volume element is just a simple scalar, and therefore calculating the maximum of the probability density would be the answer

Comment: The probability of finding the electron at a point is *zero*.

Comment: More precisely, you are finding the probability of an electron occupying an infinitesimal volume element about a point.

Comment: And further to @MattHanson's point, the size of an infinitesimal volume element bounded by $\Delta r$, $\Delta \theta $, and $\Delta \phi $ varies from point to point in space. This "weights" the infinitesimal probabilities differently and leads to the difference in the functional forms that you found.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I thought about this, but when answering the question "what is the coordinates that maximises the probability of finding an electron", which one is correct? What physically does this question mean if, depending on coordinates, we get different functional forms when considering the probability of finding an electron in an infinitesimal volume. Isn't "the coordinate that maximises the probability of finding an electron", one that refers to the probability in an infinitesimal volume element

Comment: Only if the infinitesimal volume elements that you're comparing have the same infinitesimal volume.  Otherwise, you're giving an "advantage" to the points where the volume elements are larger.  In Cartesian coordinates, all volume elements have the same size, but they don't all have the same size in spherical coordinates.  This is explained relatively well in [Rishi's answer below.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/789996/81133)

Comment: As another side comment, this distinction is closely related to the distinction between the point where the hydrogen ground state wavefunction is maximized ($r = 0$) and the most likely radius at which the electron can be found ($r = a_0$).  The key is to realize that while the probability per unit volume is greater near the center, there is "more volume" at greater radii.

Comment: I myself was aware of the coordinate dependance of the size of the volume element dv in spherical coordinates, however now I am left slightly confused when people equate $$dxdydz = r^2 sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi$$ Since these strictly are not the same thing. So really to sum up my thinking from all of the coments I have received. - the point at which the probability DENSITY is a maximum, is independant of the choice of coordinates used. The maximum of the ACTUAL probability of finding an electron located in a small dv element IS dependant on the choice of coordinates used.

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the question that was asked of me that inspired my question, please can you look at it and try to interpret what it actually means, since according to your comments I am taking that:^.maximising the probability density  and maximising the probability of finding an electron in a region dv are not the same thing when considering spherical coordinates

Comment: Frankly, the question in the screenshot is not well-written: it makes the common mistake of talking about the probability of a measurement at a point (which is, formally, zero for every point). The _probability density_ as a function of the radius (which I shall call $\mathbb{P}(r)$) is the integral of $\psi^2(r,\theta,\phi)$ over $\theta$ and $\phi$ (watch out for the Jacobian), and the thin spherical shell of maximum probability is the shell between $r_0+\delta r$, if $r_0$ is the coordinate of the maximum of $\mathbb{P}(r)$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that more cautions notation and terminology would make this less confusing.

The probability of a measurement in a *cuboid-shaped* volume bounded by $x\in(x',x'+\delta x)$, $y\in(y',y'+\delta y),$ and $z\in(z'+\delta z)$ is $$P(\mathcal{V})= \int_{x'}^{x'+\delta x}\int_{y'}^{y'+\delta y}\int_{z'}^{z'+dz}|\psi(x,y,z)|^2  \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z.$$
This expression is cautions about making sure that the integration bounds and integration variables have distinct names. More importantly, it is exactly true: there is no limit necessary. If you approximate $\psi$ to be constant over a small region, you can exchange the integrals for a factor of the enclosed volume $\mathcal{V}$, $$P(\mathcal{V})\approx|\psi(x,y,z)|^2\delta x\,\delta y\,\delta z=|\psi(x,y,z)|^2\mathcal{V}.$$

These observations do not change the fact that we do indeed have the result you stated for the probability of measurement in a sufficiently small volume of space in spherical coordinates (with no assumptions regarding separability of the potential $V$), $$P(r,\theta,\phi) \approx|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 r^2 \sin(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\ \mathrm{d}\phi.$$ The factor $r^2\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi$ is the volume element in spherical coordinates, so you will indeed recover $$|\psi(x,y,z)^2|\mathcal{V}=|\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2\mathcal{V},$$
and a similar relation for the maximum value on each side.

---

This is not strictly relelvant, but $|\psi(x,y,z)|^2 = \psi^2_{x}(x)\psi^2_{y}(y)\psi^2_{z}(z)$ is only valid if the potential $V$ is separable; the proof of this claim can be found in most QM textbooks (when the dust settles, it is just separation of variables).

Comment: Your last comment is not strictly correct.  You can always separate the solution $\psi(x,y,z)$ once you have it - you can always use brute force and numerically integrate - but it might not be easy to *find* the solution (especially analytically) if you use a poor choice of coordinates.

Comment: "and a similar relation for the maximum value on each side" in one side, when finding the coordinate that maximises then probability, we obtain that the volume element is constant, and thus only globally scales the function which does not impact the point of maximum. But in spherical coordinates, the volume element scales the coordinates dependant on the variables, and thus we get a different maximum.

Comment: @jensenpaull however, finding the "coordinate" that maximizes probability isn't possible, because at any single point, the probability of measurement is zero. You need to integrate that probability density over a volume (but possibly infinitesimally small one). Thus, when you're taking the maximum of each side of that equation, you should be looking for the small volume containing maximum probability, and you will not be allowed to simply drop the $\mathcal{V}$s: the different expression for the volume element on each side will account for the scaling effect you mentioned.